When is an unbounded averaging operator on $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ closed?
Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following linear operator $A$ on functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$:
$$(Af)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n f(x+n)+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n f(x-n).$$ If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is in $L^1$, this is a bounded $L^2\to L^2$ operator. Assume from now on that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is not in $L^1$ or even in $L^2$; then it is easy to see that $A$ is not a bounded operator (in the $L^2\to L^2$ sense).
Is there a simple criterion (sufficient, necessary or (preferably) both) for when $f$ is a closed operator? Or for when $\ker f$ is closed? (If $f$ is a closed operator, then $\ker f$ is closed; is there an implication in the opposite direction in this case?)

On which domain is $A$ defined? The set of functions in $L^2$ for which the series converge absolutely in $L^2$, or something else?

@MaoWao Sure, that's a natural domain of definition.

If you take the Fourier transform, the operator $A$ is equivalent to the multiplication by $f(\xi)=2 \sum_n a_n \cos (n \xi)$ which is closed whenver the sum converges a.e. By the way, $f$ can be bounded, hence $A$ is bounded,  even though $(a_n) \not \in l^1$.

@GiorgioMetafune: I think the OP meant that $A$ is unbounded if $a_n\notin\ell^2$, which is indeed obvious.

@GiorgioMetafune, can your comment be made into a complete answer? It seems that the operator is densely defined iff your function $f$ is finite a.e. and then the operator is always closed.

@MateuszWasilewski I am not sure I can prove that. $Af$ is defined for all $f$ for which $A_N f =\sum_{-N}^N a_n f(x+n)$ converges in $L^2$ or, equivalently, $\sum_{-N}^{N} a_n \cos (n \xi) \hat{f}(\xi)$ converges in $L^2$. But then I do not know...can you prove more?

Maybe I was a bit too quick. Since almost everywhere convergence is very poorly behaved, one should look into (local) convergence in measure? Up to passing to a subsequence it is the same but maybe more manageable. For instance, if $f_n \xi$ converges in $L^2$ to some $g$ then on any finite measure subset of the support of $\xi$ the sequence $f_n$ converges in measure to $\frac{g}{\xi}$. I guess by density one can show that there is an almost everywhere defined function to which $f_n$ converges locally in measure.
